# Databinding error with viewmodel bindings

Tags: android, android-databinding

I've started getting databinding errors after adding some bindings in the layout that reference LiveData objects from my viewmodel. I've done this plenty of times in other layouts and I never had this problem. The error does not shed much light on what is wrong.

This is the error message

```
CheckoutBindingImpl.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        java.lang.String callbackArg_0 = android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.getTextString(firstName);
                                                ^
  symbol:   variable databinding
  location: variable android of type Button
/home/Droids/vv/sample-app/app/build/generated/source/kapt/stageCheckoutDebug/com/sample/databinding/FragmentCheckoutBindingImpl.java:685: error: cannot find symbol
        android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.setTextWatcher(this.firstName, (android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.BeforeTextChanged)null, (android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged)null, (android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.AfterTextChanged)null, firstNameandroidTextAttrChanged);
               ^
  symbol:   variable databinding
  location: variable android of type Button
/home/Droids/vv/sample-app/app/build/generated/source/kapt/stageCheckoutDebug/com/sample/databinding/FragmentCheckoutBindingImpl.java:713: error: cannot find symbol
        android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.setText(this.firstName, viewModelFirstNameGetValue);
               ^
  symbol:   variable databinding
  location: variable android of type Button
Note: /home/Droids/vv/sample-app/app/build/generated/source/kapt/stageCheckoutDebug/com/sample/injection/DaggerAppComponent.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
```

This is part of the layout:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        style="@style/CheckoutInputField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/checkout_edit_text_height"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@={viewModel.firstName}"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/last_name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_label" />
```

And this is the viewmodel:

```
abstract class CheckoutViewModel : ViewModel() {
    abstract var cartNavigator: CartNavigator?

    abstract val firstName: MutableLiveData<String>

    /* other stuff *
}
```

The viewmodel implementation is straigthforward:

```
class CheckoutViewModelImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider
) : CheckoutViewModel() {
    override val firstName = MutableLiveData<String>()

    /* other stuff *
}
```

This is part of the autogenerated class where one of the errors is thrown (line with android.databinding.adapters):

```
    if ((dirtyFlags & 0x800L) != 0) {
        // api target 1

        this.android.setOnClickListener(mCallback58);
        this.apple.setOnClickListener(mCallback59);
        this.back.setOnClickListener(mCallback55);
        this.debitCredit.setOnClickListener(mCallback56);
        android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.setTextWatcher(this.firstName, (android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.BeforeTextChanged)null, (android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.OnTextChanged)null, (android.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter.AfterTextChanged)null, firstNameandroidTextAttrChanged);
        this.paypal.setOnClickListener(mCallback57);
    }
```

Here's also a screenshot of one of the errors from the autogenerated file:

[image: Binding error]

Any suggestions about what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

For all those, who are getting this error, please make sure that you haven't accidentally set the android:id as "@+id/android". In my case, the id was set as android.
After changing the id, error was fixed.